# How do you determine if a picture needs to be rotated?

Tags: iphone, coldfusion

I have my students upload a picture of themselves, but the iPhone users are habitually uploading sideways images.

Q: How do I determine that the picture is sideways, and can I rotate it automatically?

Comment: I think your best bet is to show them a preview once it's uploaded and let them turn it if it's needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with [Busches](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1200805/busches) that you should show a preview and allow manual override for your user interface.  That being said, you do have a way in ColdFusion to get exif data and to view the orientation information.  [Pete Freitag](http://www.petefreitag.com/) has an article on how to programatically retrieve information using the cfimage tag:

http://www.petefreitag.com/item/657.cfm

It looks like CF translates the Orientation data into text, so the challenge will be to translate from the raw information, which would be a numerical value as described in [EXIF Orientation Handling is a Ghetto](http://recursive-design.com/blog/2012/07/28/exif-orientation-handling-is-a-ghetto/).

The best bet would be to take test images with your device(s) in various orientaitons and see what the data show.

Comment: There is a difference between orientation and "sideways". Tony's solution will help with orientation but short expensive software that actually tries to "look" at the picture, I agree with @busches you need users need to be able to "lay eyes" on what they have uploaded and determine whether or not it needs to be rotated

Comment: I think I agree.  Thank you for all the advice!